# How to correctly return an array for further use?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, smarty

I have the following code on my site:

```
$statusMessageSQL = "SElECT * FROM statusmessages";
$statusMessagePrepare = $db->prepare($statusMessageSQL);
$statusMessagePrepare->execute();
$statusMessageResult = $statusMessagePrepare->fetchAll();
foreach($statusMessageResult as $row){
    $row['username']=$db->getUsername($db->getUserNameById($row['posterID']));
    $results[] = $row;
    $smarty->assign('results', $results);
}
```

It works without any problems, but now I wanted to put most of this in my database class to work more object oriented. But I have some problems returning the array. I have done this

```
$statusMessage = $db->getStatusMessages();
var_dump($statusMessage);
```

The function:

```
function getStatusMessage(){
    $statusMessageSQL = "SElECT * FROM statusmessages";
    $statusMessagePrepare = $db->prepare($statusMessageSQL);
    $statusMessagePrepare->execute();
    $statusMessageResult = $statusMessagePrepare->fetchAll();
    foreach($statusMessageResult as $row){
        $row['username']=$db->getUsername($db->getUserNameById($row['posterID']));
        $results[] = $row;
}
    return $results;

}
```

But this just tells me, that my array is null. so there have to be an problem with my returning. How do I do it correctly?

My database entries are statusID, posterID, statusMessage, dateTime, sumRating and sumVotes.

And what do I do if I want to also return an entry of another table? Like, I have the givenName and familyName of the poster (posterID) on another table. How do I also return this data?

Comment: You are calling `$db->getStatusMessages` and showing us `$db->getStatusMessage` (without an **s**). Which is correct here?

Comment: In function getStatusMessage(), use $results = array(); // Always initialize variable before use

Comment: What slugonamission said helped me a lot. I'm such an blind idiot. Thanks, I'm now working on it

Comment: i will be better if you put some detail before your coding that what are you trying to do with `getStatusMessages`. are you only want >all the status messages > with their username(form some other table) > and also familyName and givenName (form 3rd table) as you said in last.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it. First of all, I made the mistake, that I - as @slugonamission said - that I made a spelling mistake in the function name. Then, I changed my forloop in the home.php from

```
$statusMessage = $db->getStatusMessage();
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($statusMessage); $i++){
$smarty->assign('results', $statusMessage[$i]);
}
```

to this, because the [$i] at the end made the forloop only use the last entry of the database and from that only the first letter.

```
$statusMessage = $db->getStatusMessage();
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($statusMessage); $i++){
$smarty->assign('results', $statusMessage);
}
```

Now what I'm working on is how to get data from other tables, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getStatusMessage(){
    global $db; // this is what you actually need to make function work

    $sql = "SElECT s.*, username FROM statusmessages s JOIN users u ON posterID.=u.id";
    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();
    return $stm->fetchAll();
}
```

note that you have to use JOIN to get associated info

Answer (score -1):

You have to parse your `$db` variable to your function:

```
function my_function() {
  global $db;

  // some code
}
```

or to use it like this:

```
class myClass {
  private $db;

  public function __construct() {

    $this->db = new MySQLi("host","user","pass","db");

  }

  public function my_function() {
    $my_db_query = $this->db->query('query');
  }
}
```

Comment: I now fixed all of the errors, but now I'm getting this erro:

 Warning: Illegal string offset 'statusID' in F:\xampp\htdocs\FinalYear\smarty\templates_c\ab89063f543bf0a8fe20c45b89aad63b616cd7c5.file.home.html.php on line 94